# Unable to make Gauge chart (using Recharts Pie) fit the container

Tags: reactjs, pie-chart, recharts

I have a basic Gauge chart (see below) component that renders a PieChart with startAngle={180} and endAngle={0}, but I'm unable to make it fit the container...

How it looks like right now:

[image]

How it's supposed to look like:

[image]

Here is a demo of a basic version: https://codesandbox.io/s/recharts-playground-3zibx

Answer (score 1):

Use the cy props and assign value in percentage. Ex. cy={'70%'}.

```
<div style={{ width: 500, height: 260, border: "1px solid black" }}>
  <PieChart height={260} width={500}>
    <Pie startAngle={180}
         endAngle={0}
         innerRadius="55%"
         data={data}
         dataKey="value"
         labelLine={false}
         blendStroke
         isAnimationActive={false}
         cy={"70%"}>
      <Cell fill="#000" />
      <Cell fill="#eaeaea" />
    </Pie>
    </PieChart>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use margin top and bottom. For example for (width:500, height: 260) you should set (top:760, bottom: 500):

> To use full width and stick to bottom:
>
> Top = Width + Height, Bottom = Width

```
<div style={{ width: 500, height: 260, border: "1px solid black" }}>
      <PieChart height={260} width={500} margin={{ top: 760, bottom: 500 }}>
        <Pie
          startAngle={180}
          endAngle={0}
          innerRadius="56%"
          data={data}
          dataKey="value"
          labelLine={false}
          blendStroke
          isAnimationActive={false}
        >
          <Cell fill="#000" />
          <Cell fill="#eaeaea" />
        </Pie>
      </PieChart>
    </div>
```

Comment: That's very counter-intuitive... How do you calculate those two values based on height and width of the container? In my case height/width aren't fixed values

Comment: First to use full width: top = width + height, bottom= width, in this way it uses maximum width and stick to the bottom edge.

Comment: It kinda works, and thanks for that... but it seems like a very workaround-ish solution... I don't understand that calculation at all

Comment: Also, it keeps throwing errors like the following when those values are used for margin: Error: <rect> attribute height: A negative value is not valid. ("-672")

Comment: I can not reproduce that errors in my development environment. But you're right and there may be some easier ways to achieve your requirements than this calculations.